# Fancybox - How to disable right click

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I manually open fancybox (see code below). How to disable right click? The example found in fancyapps.com does not work for me...

```
<a class="Farma_Iluzji" href="javascript:;">zdjęcia</a>
<script>
        $(".Farma_Iluzji").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open([
                    '/photo_gallery/Galerie/Farma Iluzji/images/20150502_162041.jpg',
                    '/photo_gallery/Galerie/Farma Iluzji/images/20150502_172042.jpg',
                    '/photo_gallery/Galerie/Farma Iluzji/images/20150502_172555.jpg',
                    '/photo_gallery/Galerie/Farma Iluzji/images/20150502_173316.jpg',
                    '/photo_gallery/Galerie/Farma Iluzji/images/20150502_173330.jpg',
                    '/photo_gallery/Galerie/Farma Iluzji/images/20150502_174559.jpg'
                    ], 
                    {
                    autoPlay : false,
                    playSpeed : 3000,
                    helpers : {
                        thumbs : true,
                        overlay : {
                            css : {
                                'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85)'
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }) 
        }); 
        </script>
```

Comment: I like being able to right click. Don't do that.

Comment: Just for learning :)

Comment: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful ==> No.3

Comment: As I have said these examples don't work for me aka I can't use it with my code... I use direct open call instead of class constructor metod.

Comment: Sorry but yes, you can use any if those examples in your code regardless you are using a manual method; just insert the callback in your code along the other API options

Comment: Thx JFK for comment. Could you show how to put beforeShow function from FancyBox examples into my code above please?

    $(".fancybox")
        .attr('rel', 'gallery')
        .fancybox({
            beforeShow: function () {
                /* Disable right click */
                $.fancybox.wrap.bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
                        return false; 
                });
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need this but I guess is to prevent saving the images.
To disable the right click you can use:

```
<script language="javascript">
document.onmousedown=disableclick;
status="Right Click Disabled";
Function disableclick(event)
{
  if(event.button==2)
   {
     alert(status);
     return false;    
   }
}
</script>
```

---

**Note:**

There are many ways to save the images besides using right click.

Comment: Thx for reply. Roughly speaking I'm not a Javascript programmer but I would like to learn/understand some basics of jQuery/Fancybox to be able to use it on my simple WWW page:) So with this example I meant how to disable right click on fancybox only. Generally I would like to know how to use fancybox callbacks but not with class constructor but with direct calls of fancybox (see my example).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fancyBox3, then you can use option `protect` (e.g., `protect:true`) that will disable right click on the content.